# Wordpress Index.php not loading

Tags: wordpress, apache2

I'm a newbie here. I installed a wordpress in a server run by Apache2. But the wordpress doesn't load index.php page. I can access deshboard and all other categories are displaying well. but the home url is not loading the index.php. Eventhough i try to added /index.php at the end of my url, still it's not working. It just display 404 error. When i look at the theme directory and wordpress directory, there are (index.php) files.

so I googled for solution. some suggested to add 
`directoryindex index.php` in `.htaccess` file. I did that and that result in 500 internal server error.

Some post in google suggest to look at dir.conf and httpd.conf under Apache2. In my httpd.conf file, I have this line of code

`SSLcertificateChainfile /etc/ssl/certs/secure_yosalasd_org.ca-bundle`

In my dir.conf file, I have this lines of code

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
```

I don't seem to find answer to this problem.I would appreciate if anyone can figure out what is the problem here.

thank you so much in advance

regards

Khun

Answer (score 3):

This may be a long shot, but once saw a simillar problem which in the end the problem was that there was an index.html file as well in the folder.
Make sure such file does not exist.

And did you try re-installing?

Comment: thank you so much for your response, i don't find any index.html fine in wordpress directory or in theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

may be the premits of htaccess disallow it from working, that will result not found pages

if you uploaded the script though root access

try this command

```
chown -hR user:user folder_path;chmod -R 644 folder_path/*.php
```

replace user by your user name, replace folder path by the full path of wordpress

## Edit:

The problem is your theme not include index.php

try to explore your theme directory, and check if there is index.php file, or switch to another theme

if the file is exists, Try to change file permissions use the command that i provided above again, i've edited it

Comment: Hi even I try to run the command, doesn't seem to work at all. when i open the website, it just keep loading the 404.php file. it's calling all the header functions, and sidebar functions as well. But the home url is not displaying index.php file. thank you

Comment: thank you so much for your patient and help. As you suggested i check my theme folder and there is index.php. to ensure that the problem is not with the theme, i change to another theme. but still the problem remain. I'm a newbie here. so please check is my command line correct chow -hR root:root /var/www; chmod -R 664 /var/www/*.php . i don't know if the command lie is correct. thank you so much again

Comment: when i type in the command line, no change at all. thank again

Comment: hi abit more update. I try to change index.php in wordpress folder to testindex.php . the result is that the website just show a list of file exist in the folder. but when i rename the file into index.php, then the website come up again, but it is not calling the template index.php. Does that mean the apache is working properly but the problem is with wordpress? what is the most likely problem here?

Comment: @khun i am sorry, I'm too late, if you sure the categories and posts and tags working fine, that's mean the problem is your wordpress can't reach the index.php file of the theme, try to check your permalink options, or try to reinstall the wordpress script

Answer (score 0):

You can change main diretory and sub directory all php files permission with this SSH Command

```
find /top/level/directory -type f -name "*.php" -print | xargs chmod 644
```